# Problems with Bootstrap Responsive Images

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have to create a responsive web site app based on the Bootstrap 3 framework.

The Bootstrap 3 way of making things responsive is to have a grid-layout of 12 columns that scale down.

I understand that Bootstrap 3 designs for mobile first and scales up(!!).

The issue is that no matter how I recode the permutations of the 12-column grid system, and no matter if I define min-width, min-height, max-width, max-height, width, height, etc. of the image to define fixed dimensions, the image either scales down really small, or it scales really big - and my client does not like this!!

Here below is code I am working on.  First is the HTML code, and then the accompanying CSS code below that is in a separate style sheet (that works fine).

Thank you very much for any help in solving the matter.

```
<!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
<!-- <header> -->
  <!-- BEGIN container for HEADER DIV -->
    <!-- BEGIN DIV for top header DIVs -->
    <div id="headerdivs" class="pad-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid" style="height: 200px;">


          <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background: blue;">
             <p class="lead"></p>
           </div>     

          <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background: red;">
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <span class="logotop"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" height="200" width="168" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></a></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background: blue;">
            <p class="lead"></p>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END DIV for top header DIVs -->
  <!-- END container for HEADER DIV -->
<!-- </header> -->
<!-- END HEADER -->

.logotop {

    position:relative;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 168px;
    max-height: 168px;
    min-height: 168px;
    z-index:1001;
}
```

Comment: and what do you expect to happen ?

Comment: do you mean such effect: http://www.bootply.com/JKwJuaHDes

Comment: @Danko, I expected the image to scale to smaller size only, but stay the defined size when the resolution is larger.

Comment: @Banzay, yes this is the responsive effect - but the one color of blue is not optimum for demonstrating the effects of scaling on images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you're including the full and unedited version of the Bootstrap CSS - https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

The issue that you're having is that within the CSS there is a declaration to ensure that all images are set to be 100%, and with an `!important` to override any other settings.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%!important
}
```

The CSS you have included in only targeting the `.logotop` class, and in order of css specificity the Bootstrap style for teh `img` will win out.

Include this as your CSS instead:

```
.logotop img {
    //your styles here
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was able to solve this problem by placing this image in the Bootstrap "navbar-brand" class in top header navigation bar, and then finding code to move this brand to the center of the page (which brought up more issues), but such is development/programming:  solving one issue raises more issues that need to be solved incrementally.

Comment: Yay, always great when you can solve your own problems. Please mark your question as solved now.